# Splitting unseparated string and numerical variables in R

Tags: r, split, strsplit

I have transformed a Pdf to text file and I have a data set which is constructed as follow:

```
data=c("Paris21London3Tokyo51San Francisco38")
```

And I would like to obtain the following structure:

```
matrix(c("Paris","London","Tokyo","San Francisco",21,3,51,38),4,2)
```

Does anyone have a method to do it ? Thanks

Comment: You can't have a matrix with numbers and strings in, so your last line ends up as a matrix of strings. Did you really want that? Otherwise what you want is a data frame with a string and a numeric column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regular expressions are the right tool here, but unlike the other answer shows, `strsplit` is *not* well suited for the job.

Better use [regular expression *matches*](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/grep.html), and to have two separate expressions for words and numbers:

```
words = '[a-zA-Z ]+'
numbers = '[+-]?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?'
word_matches = gregexpr(words, data)
number_matches = gregexpr(numbers, data)

result = cbind(regmatches(data, word_matches)[[1]],
               regmatches(data, number_matches)[[1]])
```

This recognises any number with an optional decimal point, and an optional sign. It does *not* recognise numbers in scientific (exponential) notation. This can be trivially added, if necessary.

Comment: I'd use `[[:digit:]]+` (one or more digits) for number match and `[^[:digit:]]+` (one or more non-digits) for word match. That will catch hyphens and apostrophes and such.

Comment: @Spacedman `[[:digit:]]` is exactly identical to `\\d`. Regarding the non-digit match, this can be accomplished by `\\D`. I didn’t use it here because I didn’t know what exactly OP wanted to match.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Initially, I thought about using similar strategies with `str_extract` (+1)

Comment: I'd prefer the readable version. You could also use `\\D+` for the word pattern but I think uppercase D for -not-digits- is dumb - only a few of the regexp escapes negate on uppercasing. Wevs.

Comment: @Spacedman I’d argue that the more concise `\\d` is more readable than the (longer, and exactly as information rich) `[[:digits:]]`. It’s just a matter of learning regular expression syntax.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Thks for your code which is clever and elegant. However it does not work with decimal numbers. Do you see a possibility to change your code so as to do it ? Thks !

Answer (score 4):

You could try `strsplit` with `regex` `lookahead` and `lookbehind`

```
v1 <- strsplit(data, '(?<=[^0-9])(?=[0-9])|(?<=[0-9])(?=[^0-9])',
                      perl=TRUE)[[1]]
 indx <- c(TRUE, FALSE)
 data.frame(Col1= v1[indx], Col2=v1[!indx])
```

#### Update

Including decimal numbers as well

```
 data1=c("Paris21.53London3Tokyo51San Francisco38.2")
 v2 <- strsplit(data1, '(?<=[^0-9.])(?=[0-9])|(?<=[0-9])(?=[^0-9.])',
                         perl=TRUE)[[1]]

 indx <- c(TRUE, FALSE)
 data.frame(Col1= v2[indx], Col2=v2[!indx])
 #           Col1  Col2
 #1         Paris 21.53
 #2        London     3
 #3         Tokyo    51
 #4 San Francisco  38.2
```

Comment: Great! It is exactly what I was looking for. Thks !!

Comment: However it does not work with decimal numbers. Do you see a possibility to change your code so as to do it ? Thks !